# How do I interpret this error of integration example in the SCIPY docs?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, parameter-passing

[This SCIPY doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) shows how to integrate a function and return 5 outputs as:

```
scipy.integrate.quad(func, a, b, args=(), full_output=0, epsabs=1.49e-08, epsrel=1.49e-08, limit=50, points=None, weight=None, wvar=None, wopts=None, maxp1=50, limlst=50)
```

Near the bottom of the page is an example in which the function e^(-x) is integrated from 0 to infinity with respect to x as:

```
>>> invexp = lambda x: np.exp(-x)
>>> integrate.quad(invexp, 0, np.inf)

(1.0, 5.842605999138044e-11)
```

This part makes sense. The example then continues as:

```
>>> f = lambda x,a : a*x
>>> y, err = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1, args=(1,))
>>> y
0.5
>>> y, err = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1, args=(3,))
>>> y
1.5
```

What do the numbers in `args=(numbers,))` represent? How is it used in the function, and how does the function know how to use it? How are the outputs `0.5` and `1.5` obtained with the `num` in `args`?

Is it correct to say that whatever the numbers in `args=(numbers,))` are, they can never be changed? If so, is it possible to pass two sets of `args`; the first set consisting of unchangeable inputs and the second set of mutable `args` (perhaps for mutable parameters `a` and `b` in an integrable Gaussian distribution function)?

**PS -- I can remove the code and extra thoughts below if it's too long and irrelevant.**

I am thinking this method may help me generalize my code such that an unchangeable argument can be added to my functions to choose which type of distribution to integrate over if multiple distribution functions are defined. Though they are I have a way of passing unchangeable `args` in a distribution function as:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def distribution( x , a , b ): ## GAUSSIAN
    ## add unchangeable input pick_distribution to specify which distribution if multiple distributions are definable
    a = abs(a) ## mu
    b = abs(b) ## sigma
    cnorm = 1 / ( b * ( 2*pi )**(1/2) )
    return cnorm * exp( (-1) * (x - a)**2 / ( 2 * (b **2) ) )

def integratesubs( args ):
    ## args[0] = a
    ## args[1] = b
    ## if the interval is 0 to 5, the subintervals could be 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc; these are generalizable
    ## integral over one subinterval is equal to area under Gaussian curve between the subinterval bounds
    ## numobs is a pre-defined sample size
    res = []
    for i in range(len(subintervalbounds)-1): ## ith i does not exist for rightmost boundary
        res.append( quad( distribution , subintervalbounds[ i ] , subintervalbounds[ i + 1 ],
                         args = ( args[0] , args[1] ))[0] * numobs )
    return res
```

Another function that calls `integratesubs` (not shown) from higher up the chain takes an input `parameters = [a,b]` as mutable inputs.

Comment: The second parameter `a` of the lambda (the slope) in your example gets passed to quad via the named argument tuple `args`. So, `1` and `3` are the slopes that are used in this particular example. If the lambda had a 3rd parameter (`b` say) you'd have to pass a tuple of len 2 (e.g., `args=(4, 7)`). `quad` supplies the `x` (between 0 and 1 in this example) and you are responsible to supply the unchanging parameters via the args tuple.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Since `quad` will integrate with the first variable (`x` in this case), I take this to mean that the `args` will pass to the parameters (`a` and `b` in this case) in the order listed in the lambda statement (if say `f = lambda x,a,b : a*x + b`). Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly correct.